# Use value from other list in calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have created a number of lists in Sharepoint. Now I want to create a calculated column for one of these lists. For this calculation I need a value from another list. In Sharepoint, can you look up a value from another list (i.e. not select or fill it with a Lookup column) and use it in calculated columns?

In Excel I would solve this with Vertical Search, is there such a thing in Sharepoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of SharePoint calculated columns.

Calculated column formula can only reference the column values from same list item/row. It cannot access column values (data) from other lists in SharePoint site.

Even if you use lookup columns, those are not supported in calculated column formula.